# C# and SQL: Selecting a row, a get a column data to a variable

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

So basically i have an SQL server. I have 4 columns. I will design this table here:

```
   varchar varchar  int    varchar
    account password gmlevel pics
    test    test           3  url
```

First, my method checks that the entered account and password is equal (login query).

Then i want to check that the 'test' account how high acces (gmlevel) has to this, then save it to a variable.

It's need to be two query. But the gmlevel record is a very important to my program, and it's not working at all.

Here is my connection:

```
private void gmset () 
    {
        if (loggedin == true) {
            try
        {
            using (var con2 = new SqlConnection())
            {
                string user = login.felhasz;
                string query2 = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE account=@acc";

                con2.ConnectionString = "connection string";
                con2.Open();
                var cm2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con2);
                cm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acc", user);

                SqlDataReader dr2 = cm2.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr2.HasRows)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ASD");
                }

            }

        }

        catch (Exception exe) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exe.Message);
        }
        }
       else {
      MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
      }
```

This code doesn't hold anything that you can use for getting the GMLevel. I've tried many things, i've been looking for answer now a day ago, still nothing.

/Sorry for multiple questioning but i'm getting further and closer to solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `Read()` method to get the gmlevel.

Try This:

```
 int GameLevel;
 while (dr2.Read())
 {
    int.TryParse(dr2["gmlevel"].ToString(),out GameLevel);
    MessageBox.Show("ASD");
 }
```

**EDIT:** i suspect that control is not entering the while loop.

Try This: Replace/Comment your `while` loop with following `if-else` block and see the results

```
 if(dr2.Read())
 {
  MessageBox.Show("Record Found");        
 }
 else
 {
  MessageBox.Show("Record Not Found!!!");        
 }
```

Comment: NOPE, again just no. I don't get nor message box either error. Simply don't work.

Comment: could you please debug and see whether the control goes to while loop or not?

Comment: Interesting. I set two breakponints. When i set it to int.TryParse line, it wasn't broken at all!! (But while (dr2.Read()) did) So the problem is that it isn't reading?

Comment: check my edited answer , try that and see what is the result.

Comment: yes, then could you please debug and check what is the `user` value?

Comment: the user value is a `textbox.Text` from an another Form. But i'm trying to give it manually for it, and see what'll happen.

`public static string felhasz;
felhasz = username.Text;`

Comment: does  `user` variable has any value while debugging?

Comment: You won't believe this. I set the user to `test`, and wrote your first code into my code, and the messagebox said ASD, SO IT'S THE USER....

Answer (score 0):

```
while (dr2.HasRows) 
{
  Object[] output = new Object[dr2.FieldCount];
  dr2.GetValues(output);

  MessageBox.Show(output[2].ToString());
}
```